# Netgear FVS338 SNMP and OID

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp, oid, net-snmp

I downloaded SNMPWalk.exe and I ran the following:

```
snmpwalk.exe -r:192.168.2.254 -p:161 -c:"public" -os:.1.3.1.1.4.1.4526
```

I ended up with over 900 something OID options. How do I know what they do and how do I properly graph them or find graphs to work with them?

I should also mention I don't know much about OID and what it is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are going to need some software to store and graph them.  Like Solarwinds NPM, MRTG or something similiar.  The OIDs are typically grouped together.  if you scroll down the dump you wi8ll see the titles and typically below or above that, you will see the data related to that title.  I use these in Orion NPM to pull printer consumables levels from printers that aren't supported by NPM directly.  It works great, but took a bit of fiddling to figure out what i needed and if I had to do math to get the levels.  for instance, one printer stores the ink level as a value between 0 and 480 mL.  to get a percentage, I had to do the math to calc it back to 0-100.